# Displaying XY chart using SQLite database data in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have the battery charging connect time (date time field - represented as String) and TimeToCharge (seconds - can be displayed as float if required) fields in SQLite database. I would like to display a XY graph of connect time on X axis and time to charge on y axis. I googled and found a lot of charting api's or jar's in android, but after having implemented a few like kiChart, I was a bit confused, that wrt my requirement, which charting solution in android would best fit. I don't want to display a very dynamic / high detail graph, but then doing a try of each and every charting solution available, would consume lot of time.

So, I can definately try and implement the one which will work out for my requirement. Could you please guide, as to which one you think, is the best and free charting solution.

Thanks
Omkar Ghaisas

```
public class BatteryGraph extends Activity 
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset;
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer;
List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
private GraphicalView mChartView;
private TimeSeries time_series;

// chart container
private LinearLayout layout;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.graph);

    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);

    // create dataset and renderer
    mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setPointSize(5f);
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {0,20,20,0});

    XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    r.setPointStyle(PointStyle.POINT);
    r.setFillPoints(true);
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
    mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(20);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true);
    mRenderer.setFitLegend(true);
    mRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    mRenderer.setInScroll(true);
    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
    mRenderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
    mRenderer.setShowLabels(true);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsAngle(60);
    mRenderer.setXTitle("Date");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Time in Secs");

    time_series = new TimeSeries("Charging Date vs TimeTakenToCharge");

    mDataset.addSeries(time_series);

    fillData();

    mChartView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer, "dd/mm/yy");

    layout.addView(mChartView);
}

private void fillData() 
{
    DatabaseAppBlock dbHelper = new DatabaseAppBlock(getApplicationContext());
    Cursor chargeCycleData = dbHelper.getAllChargeCycleData("Asc");
    int rowCount = chargeCycleData.getCount();

    if(rowCount > 0)
    {
        chargeCycleData.moveToFirst(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount ; i++) 
        {
```

`time_series.add(CommonFunc.GetDateFromString(chargeCycleData.getString(chargeCycleData.getColumnIndex(Constants.colChargeConnectTime))),chargeCycleData.getDouble(chargeCycleData.getColumnIndex(Constants.colTimeToCharge)));
                chargeCycleData.moveToPosition(i+1);`
               }
        }
    }
}

Comment: you haven't search enough..cause there are more useful libraries available

Answer (score 1):

[AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/) is easy to use and offers a TimeChart class. This is an XY chart with a time/date axis that handles the date presentation itself. The AChartEngine demo has example code for TimeChart aswell.

Comment: I was successfully able to display the Time Chart. Thanks for the suggestion. Btw, I am still not able to allow scrolling the graph left-right. Because of that, few of my db data (dates) and their timings go out of screen. I am able to display only 3 data points as of now, but with either scroll or some other option, I would be able to display the further data points as well. Whats the technique to do that ?

Comment: You can enable horizontal scrolling by setting setPanEnabled(true, false) for your XYMultipleSeriesRenderer. The first argument is for horizontal scrolling, the second argument is for vertical scrolling.